# how to set some rows un editable in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

is there way to set some rows un editable in jqgrid after first edit is done

i tried to add class

> not-editable-row

but no luck

this is how i make all rows editable

```
onSelectRow: function(id){
  if(id && id!==lastsel){
    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    grid.editRow(id,true);
    lastsel=id;
  }
}
```

any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't posted the code which you use to add the 'not-editable-row' class to the row (`<tr>` element).

I suppose that what you need is just do this inside of `aftersavefunc` event handler of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow). So you should replace the `grid.editRow(id,true)` to the following:

```
grid.jqGrid('editRow',id,true,null,null,null,{},
            function(rowid){
                var tr = this.rows.namedItem(rowid);
                $(tr).addClass('not-editable-row');
            });
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingOnce.htm).